# ESP-iDF | input from keyboard inside a task

Tags: esp32, freertos, esp-idf

How to take input from keyboard inside a task in ESP-IDF ,

The code I have tried is

```
void xTask1(void *params)
{
    while (true)
    {
        
        char c = 0;
        char str[4];
        memset(str, 0, sizeof(str));
        while (c != '\n')
        {
            printf("Enter the value:\n");
            c = getchar();
            if (c != 0xff)
            {
                str[strlen(str)] = c;
                printf("%c", c);
            }
            vTaskDelay(100 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
        }

        int d = atoi(str);

        printf("you have typed : %d\n", d);

        
    }
}

void app_main(void)
{

    xTaskCreate(xTask1, "task1", 2048, NULL, 1, NULL);
}
```

and the output I am getting is

```
I (309) cpu_start: Starting scheduler on PRO CPU.
I (0) cpu_start: Starting scheduler on APP CPU.
Enter the value:
Enter the value:
Enter the value:
Enter the value:
Enter the value:
Enter the value:
Enter the value:
Enter the value:
Enter the value:
```

Its not holding in to enter the input,

- What is the mistake I am making here.?

Comment: First of all, C 101: getchar() returns an int, not a char, so you need an int variable for it and there's nothing special about 0xFF. On the ESP side, you probably want to disable buffering on stdin. Look at ESP's console code.

Comment: An aside....  `str[strlen(str)] = c;` not an efficient approach to loading a string buffer. You calculate a new string length each time. Why not just an index you increment? Also, you don't check if the user types in more than 3 characters (the max capacity of your `str`), so that's trouble.

Comment: But how to hold the task from reoccurring ?